# How to alter the color of an image

Tags: gimp, image-editing, microsoft-paint

I have two images here of grilled unagi (eel), this one:
[image: image of grilled unagi (eel), obtained from the Internet]
obtained from the Internet, and this one:
[image: image of grilled unagi (eel), taken by me]
taken by me. How would I, using GIMP (or, if it's even possible, with Paint), adjust the color of the unagi on the second picture to look closer to the first? The first one looks a lot more appetizing (bright, red, lively) whereas the second looks dark and scary :(. I'm not sure if this is the best place to be asking this type of question; if there's a better place, let me know! I had much success asking a similar question here earlier so figured I'd give it another go!

Comment: to be completely honest, i haven't touched image editing until recently and have little to no idea on how to approach this. what features/tools should i be using? if you can point me to a direction, i'd gladly look it up

Comment: You mention some programs - try them. Really, no one should be expected to do your explorations for you. :)

Comment: An observation: the color difference is the least of your problems if you want to make the second picture look appetizing.  If it was me and I had to eat it, I would want to do it in the dark so I couldn't see it at all.  But that's just me.  I'm sure it's tastier than it looks.  Just sayin'.  :-)

Comment: hahaha, i might have to work on my photography skills then;p

Comment: aite i more or less have it figured out, just cut out the unagi slice with Paths Tools then `Select`->`From Path` then `Colors`->`Color Path` and tune it around:D